# How to get canvas widget name from command?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I try to make popup menus that are in part defined by the widget that it was opened on. I can't seem to find a way to find which widget the menu is opened on. For example:

```
.f.canvas bind all <3> {
  puts stderr "%W just gives me '.f.canvas'"
}
```

The widget name would be used for lookup in another table to change properties of the object related to the specific widget.

Comment: The bind widget command for a canvas applies to items in the canvas. The canvas window name is fixed as you have found out. You need to supply a bit more code and information as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.f.canvas bind all <3> {
    puts stderr [%W find closest %x %y]
}
```

It should show the id of the item you clicked on.

Comment: If he's using scrolling, the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods might be needed to translate the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

When looking for some other stuff in the Tk documentation for canvas I came across [the `current` tag](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm):

> The tag **current** is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the
>   *current item*, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the
>   position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in
>   varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details).
>   If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then
>   no item has the current tag.

Example of using it:

```
.f.canvas bind all <3> {
  puts stderr "widget [%W find withtag current] says hello"
}
```